# Nomenclature: equivalent atoms by single locant

Tags: nomenclature, symmetry

Sometimes the IUPAC name is too verbose despite the structure's high symmetry. If we could use only the first locant of the ("topologically symmetrically") equivalent set of locants, and designate all of them by some symbol (e.g. x<sup>*allsym*</sup>, which is too long, and Greek letter *sigma* has some meanings already, so I will use Greek letter *stigma*), then we could have

[image]
1,3,5-trinitrohexahydro-s-triazine *vs*
1<sup>ς</sup>-trinitrohexahydro-s-triazine or
*N*<sup>ς</sup>-trinitrohexahydro-s-triazine

[image]
naphthalene-1,4,5,8-tetrol *vs*
naphthalene-1<sup>ς</sup>-tetrol

[image]
naphthalene-1,2,4,5,8-pentol *vs*
naphthalene-1<sup>ς</sup>,2-pentol

[image]
naphthalene-1,2,3,6,7-pentol *vs*
naphthalene-1,2<sup>ς</sup>-pentol

1,5(1,2,3),2,4,6,8,9(1,4),3,7(1,2)-nonabenzenabicyclo[3.3.1]nonaphane *vs*
1<sup>ς</sup>(1,2,3),2<sup>ς</sup>(1,4),3<sup>ς</sup>(1,2)-nonabenzenabicyclo[3.3.1]nonaphane

[image]
1,2,3,4,5,6-hexachlorobenzene or
hexachlorobenzene *vs*
1<sup>ς</sup>-hexachlorobenzene *(the name is not convenient in this case)*

[image]
1,2,3,4,5,6-hexachlorocyclohexane *vs*
1<sup>ς</sup>-hexachlorocyclohexane

[image]
1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6-dodecachlorocyclohexane or
perchlorocyclohexane *vs*
1<sup>ς,ς</sup>-dodecachlorocyclohexane
*(not convenient in this case, but mentioned the special feature, listing two identical sets. Imagine 1<sup>ς</sup> means 1,2,3,4,5,6; 1<sup>ς,ς</sup> would mean 1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6)*

Wrong usage can lead to contadictions/confusion, e.g. 1<sup>ς</sup>-trichlorobenzene would be illegal, because benzene carbon 1 is equivalent with all other carbons, total 6. But it is distantly similar problem like for with name like 1,2,3-hexachlorobenzene.

Is anyone aware of such feature in any chemical nomenclature?

Comment: "topologically" isn't appropriate here, as this is geometry; topology is a different thing altogether. Also your "pentol" is bad example.

Comment: Mithoron, could you explain what bad do you see on the pentol example? The "stigma" apples to the single locant immediately before the exponent, of course; and to the parent structure without any substituent that are defined by the prefixes.

Comment: gilleain, it means "all equivalent atoms", so 1* on cyclooctane means all eight carbons, so you cannot use this "stigma" for the mentioned set of positions.

Comment: Mithoron, geometry is much less appropriate term here, since you can draw cyclohexane as non-regular distorted hexagon, but the atom equivalence does not change.